# SQL Help: Select statement Concatenate a One to Many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

For example I have two tables. The first table is student while the second table are the courses that the a student is taking. How can I use a select statement so that I can see two columns student and courses so that the courses are separated by commas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2005:

This should do what you're after - obviously replace fields as you need:

For demo purposes, consider the following two table structures:

```
Students(
  STU_PKEY Int Identity(1,1) Constraint PK_Students_StuPKey Primary Key,
  STU_NAME nvarchar(64)
)

Courses(
  CRS_PKEY Int Identity(1, 1) Constraint PK_Courses_CrsPKey Primary Key,
  STU_KEY Int Constraint FK_Students_StuPKey Foreign Key References Students(STU_PKEY),
  CRS_NAME nvarchar(64)
)
```

Now this query should do the job you're after:

```
Select  s.STU_PKEY, s.STU_NAME As Student,
        Stuff((
            Select  ',' + c.CRS_NAME
            From    Courses c
            Where   s.STU_PKEY = c.STU_KEY
            For     XML Path('')
        ), 1, 1, '') As Courses 
From    Students s
Group By s.STU_PKEY, s.STU_NAME
```

Way simpler than the currently accepted answer...

Comment: Thanks I used this one and your right it is simple. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
create table Project (ProjectId int, Description varchar(50));
insert into Project values (1, 'Chase tail, change directions');
insert into Project values (2, 'ping-pong ball in clothes dryer');

create table ProjectResource (ProjectId int, ResourceId int, Name varchar(15));
insert into ProjectResource values (1, 1, 'Adam');
insert into ProjectResource values (1, 2, 'Kerry');
insert into ProjectResource values (1, 3, 'Tom');
insert into ProjectResource values (2, 4, 'David');
insert into ProjectResource values (2, 5, 'Jeff');

SELECT *, 
  (SELECT Name + ' ' AS [text()] 
   FROM ProjectResource pr 
   WHERE pr.ProjectId = p.ProjectId 
   FOR XML PATH ('')) 
AS ResourceList 
FROM Project p

--    ProjectId    Description                        ResourceList
--    1            Chase tail, change directions      Adam Kerry Tom 
--    2            ping-pong ball in clothes dryer    David Jeff
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which server you're using.  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Other?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you're talking about is a join:

```
SELECT 
    S.*,
    SC.*
  FROM
    Students S
    INNER JOIN Student_Courses SC
      ON S.student_id = SC.student_id
```

However, that will give you one row per *course*. SQL doesn't make it easy to get the set of courses as a comma delimited list in a single row (that's not a set-based operation). Depending on the vendor, there are different ways to do it, involving looping.

Answer (score 0):

I think this MySQL page will help you with that.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

So you want to see:

```
'Jade', 'Math, English, History'
'Kieveli', 'History, Biology, Physics'
```

Yes, comma separated is always desirable, but SQL isn't good at it.  Here's the approach I was always planning on using:

Create a Function on the SQL server that uses a cursor to loop over the subquery (sorry - I didn't fully test this):

```
CREATE FUNCTION commacourselist(@studentname varchar(100))
RETURNS @List varchar(4096)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @coursename varchar(100)

DECLARE FOR
SELECT course.name FROM course WHERE course.studentname = @studentname
OPEN coursecursor

FETCH NEXT FROM coursecursor INTO @coursename 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 IF @List = ''
 BEGIN
  SET @List = @coursename
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
  SET @List = @List + ',' + @coursename 
 END
 FETCH NEXT FROM coursecursor INTO @coursename 
END
CLOSE coursecursor 
DEALLOCATE coursecursor 

RETURN
END
GO
```

Then call the function in the  query:

```
SELECT student.name, 
       commacourselist( student.name )  
FROM student
```

Comment: A cursor? No!  2005's PIVOT could probably be used for this, or a custom aggregate, or the Stuff() option below, or just about _anything_ but a cursor.

Comment: Joel - do you have an example of how to use PIVOT for this?  I tried to figure that method out, but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: I saw a vague reference on how to COALESCE() to a string list, but couldn't find any concrete implementation.  I've done some PIVOTs before, and never did they show promise of creating a comma separated list.

Comment: The PIVOT will give you one column for the studentname and one column for each course (variable non-null columns for each row). You were asking for two columns, so a pivot won't exactly work.

Comment: @Kieveli: Coalesce() is great if you've got multiple columns and you want to concatenate them to a single column, but not so great if you want to concatenate multiple rows to a single.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDF that cursors through the related records and concats a return string together but this will be expensive - if you give it a go make sure your cursor is READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 2005 or 2008? If so, then lookup the PIVOT comand. It should be more efficient than a function with a cursor.